# How can I limit and insert conditions on results returned from API fetch request after using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am using Fetch with an API after it returns a 1000 objects I want to render only the first 4 or the values with the highest value

I am using .map on the results but I dont know how to put conditions or limit the .map results?

````
{NowMovies.map(Movie=>(
     <Col  sm="3">
       <Card key={Movie.id}className='Now_Playing' body>
         <CardImg top width="100%" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200${Movie.poster_path}`}
         alt=""/>
         <CardTitle className='title' >{Movie.title}</CardTitle>
         <CardText className='Text'>Rating:{Movie.vote_average}</CardText>
         <Link to={'/movie/' + Movie.id } > <Button color="danger">Visit</Button>{' '}
</Link>
       </Card>
     </Col>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with `or the values with the highest value`, though if you want to take only 4 elements from your array you can use `slice`. `slice` can work as a "limit" if you pass 0 as a first argument and number of items you want to obtains as a second argument. 
e.g

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.slice(0, 4) // [1,2,3,4]

// if you want to get your items starting from specific position:
arr.slice(1, 5) // [2,3,4,5]
```

```
{NowMovies.slice(0,4).map(Movie=>(
     <Col  sm="3">
       <Card key={Movie.id}className='Now_Playing' body>
         <CardImg top width="100%" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200${Movie.poster_path}`}
         alt=""/>
         <CardTitle className='title' >{Movie.title}</CardTitle>
         <CardText className='Text'>Rating:{Movie.vote_average}</CardText>
         <Link to={'/movie/' + Movie.id } > <Button color="danger">Visit</Button>{' '}
</Link>
       </Card>
     </Col>)}
```

Comment: Gladys , I mean if the .map will return an array which have values like this : 
{number:3 , name :x},{number :2 , name : y} ... etc. , for example I want to return the values with the number > 3 or the highest 4 values regarding its number values

Comment: Gladys , Another thing regarding your answer if this code were in a component <Movies/> and now I am trying to render the same component <Movies/> but this time I need to do the .slice can it be done directly on the component <Movies/> or I must write all the code again adding .slice.map this time
Thank you

Comment: if you want to get values with property higher than `x` you can use `filter`:
`arr.filter(obj => obj.number > 3).map(...)`

2) `slice` is not going to change your original data, it's creating a new array on fly

Answer (score 0):

```js
const NowMovies = [];
const MAX_RATING = 10;

// This is just a sample JSON array with random ratings between 1-10 in this example
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  NowMovies.push({ index: i, rating: Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_RATING + 1) });
}

// This is how you sort your array in descending order by rating, and then return the first N results.  5 in this case.
const sortedArray = NowMovies.sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating).slice(0, 5);

console.log(sortedArray);
```

You need to write a  custom sort method to define how you want to sort your array, like this ^

Then you can slice to return the first N results.

After you have modified your array, you can then use the .map to render the JSX.

Comment: great I have another thing now if the code above were written in a component in a page to be rendered with all results, But I want to use the same component in another route where I need to render only 4 of this component , I must re-write the component again and add the code you provided ? or I can use <NowMovies/> and add code to only return and render 4 of this component

Comment: You could pass a prop into the component and use that prop value as the "N" value of the slice results.  Like... <NowMovies size={20} /> .  Then you could do .slice(0, props.size || 5) to return 20 results if you have a size prop, or 5 by default.